# Imported Oracle Linux OVA into VMware Workstation & vSphere and the NIC will not come up

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, networkmanager, oracle-linux

VM was built with VirtualBox via Vagrant:

- https://yum.oracle.com/boxes/

I need a production VM, so I exported the VM from VBox -> to VMware Workstation & vSphere (both have same issue). There is an "E1000" virtual NIC for the VM (which does not require a driver from VMtools), but I cannot bring the NIC up to get an IP:

[image: Oracle-linux_network-issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the assumption that a virtualbox VM of OL9 is the same as getting it from the official channels.....it is **NOT**!

If you need OL9 in vSphere you must get the official ISO from Oracle.com and not use a Vagrant box in VBox like I did: https://yum.oracle.com/boxes/